# Why is my Insertion bubbling a higher value to the start?

Tags: c++, c++17

I used insertion sort to sort a string consisting of '+' separated digits. The digits can only be 1, 2 or 3. While I thought the code would work perfectly, it is giving me some weird outputs.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
     
    typedef long long ll;
     
    using namespace std;
     
    int main()
    {
        ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
        cin.tie(NULL);
     
        string s;
        cin >> s;
     
        for (int i = 2; i < s.size(); i += 2)
        {
            int value = s[i];
            int key = i;
            while (key > 0 && s[i-2] > value)
            {
                s[key] = s[key-2];
                key = key - 2;
            }
            s[key] = value;
        }
     
        cout << s;
    }
```

When I input

> 2+1+2+2+2+3+1+3+1+2

the output is weirdly

> 2+1+1+1+2+2+2+2+3+3

The 2 at the end is getting carried to the start.

If i remove the last 2 from the input, the result is as expected

> 2+1+2+2+2+3+1+3+1

> 1+1+1+2+2+2+2+3+3

I spent so much time debugging and can't find out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while (key > 0 && s[i-2] > value)`
You have used `s[i-2]` instead of `s[key-2]` in your code,this means as your numbers shift *all the way* to the left if `value` is smaller than `s[i-2]` instead of stopping once the number to the left is `<=` it.
TL;DR Change `s[i-2]` to `s[key-2]` and you'll be fine.

Comment: That solved it. Now that you have pointed it out it seems like an obvious error that I should've noticed. Thank You!